# remove elements not starting with a letter in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

trying remove items in  a list not beginning with letters A-E, here is what I have, but it has no effect:

```
$("div.artist_type_filter div.element div.title a").each(function(){
        if($(this).html().match(/^[a-eA-E].*$/) === null){
            $(this).remove();
        }

    });
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Check http://jsfiddle.net/FtKUq/ Make sure the selector that you have used is accurate to select the anchor elements

Comment: Can you really remove an item while you are enumerating the items?

Comment: @agent-j === is a "type equals" operator.  It checks type *and* value.  While `"5" == 5` will return true, `"5" === 5` will not because string and number type do not match. And yes you can remove elements you are iterating through.

Comment: I think it would be better to give some HTML code, so that we can find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `/^[a-eA-E].*$/` to `/^[a-eA-E]/`.

**Update**

I misunderstood. Your regex works fine. The selector might has problem. Anyway, my simpler regex also works fine.